# What is the computational complexity of Lucas-Kanade algorithm?

Tags: c++, opencv, big-o, time-complexity, opticalflow

In big-O notation for time-complexity, how much would be the complexity of Lucas-Kanade optical flow computation as implemented in OpenCV (C++)? And how did you deduce that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Assume that the number of warp parameters is `n` and the number of pixels in `T` is `N`. The total computational cost of each iteration of Lucas-Kanade algorithm is [image]. You can find such information and discussion from [Lucas-Kanade 20 Years On: A Unifying Framework: Part 1 - 2.4](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/baker_simon_2002_3/baker_simon_2002_3.pdf).

[image]

ps: I have no idea of computational complexity of the OpenCV implementation. But, to be reasonable, it *should* be the same as the above.

Comment: So, `n` the number of warp parameters, is equal to 2 while computing flow. And `N` is size of the image. True?

Comment: @a-Jays Yes, I think so.

Comment: So it doesn't depend on the number of features it is tracking? That seems counter-intuitive, and seems to defy the results.

Comment: @a-Jays No, `n` here can be viewed as the number of features.

Comment: But equation (1) in the document [on page 2] says `n` must be 2.
What am I missing?

Comment: @a-Jays It will be 2 for optical flow, i.e. counting for [`x`, `y`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow).

Comment: Exactly, and hence my second question: if `n` is 2, then the number of feature points (probably obtained by `goodFeaturesToTrack()` ) doesn't play a role in determining LK's complexity?

Comment: @a-Jays Feature points, I think, is out of LK's scope. It's more like that I can fed a cat in 5 min, how much time do I need to fed 10 cats. I know the answer is 50min here but 10 is not related to how fast I can feed cats.

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry this sounds amateurish- so perhaps the complexity deduced in that document is for _one_ feature point? In that case, it could scale with the number of points.

Comment: @a-Jays Yeah, you can think in this way. Or better to think that it's for constant-value feature points.

Comment: I'd vote this answer up, but apparently I do not have the 'reputation' for that. I'm also hoping someone would contradict or add some more to it. Thanks, for the moment!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the OpenCV github and the information in [Lucas-Kanade 20 Years On: A Unifying Framework: Part 1 - 2.4](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/baker_simon_2002_3/baker_simon_2002_3.pdf) I can say that:

In a 2D tracking algorithm `(x, y)` using Optical Flow with Lucas-Kanade [like opencv stated](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html) `n` equals `2` and `N` is the quantity of pixels on the frame, that is `(height*width)` for example in my research (Sperm tracking) i use `n=2` (2D tracking) and `T=788*388`.

This is done for every feature as I can see [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_attic/blob/2.1/opencv/src/cv/cvlkpyramid.cpp) on line 178 `for( size_t ptidx = 0; ptidx < npoints; ptidx++)`.

So `O(N*n^2 + n^3)` is for one feature and for `F` features it would be `O(F*N*n^2 + F*n^3)`.

Comment: Sorry for the link space, i can't post more than 2 links due to lack of reputation